# Exportar tabela (em pd.DataFrame) para o formato csv - Python

Tags: csv

estão bem?

Como exportar ou salvar uma tabela feita com pandas.DataFrame em formato csv ou xlsx no Python?

Answer (score 2):

exportar csv

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
```

exportar em xlsx

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

**Exemplo da documentação Pandas.DataFrame:**

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
 df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
 df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
 writer.save()
```

[Documentação Panda](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: muito obrigado :)